# Trying to install the latest CodeBlocks on Lubuntu, errors!

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu

I'm at my wits end trying to install the latest codeblocks. Having been to the site, it recommends:

> For Ubuntu, use this PPA:
>
> https://launchpad.net/~damien-moore/+archive/ubuntu/codeblocks-stable

http://codeblocks.org/downloads/26

Trying to figure out what the specific PPA is, was a nightmare, but I stumbled across this question/answer, which I got the line:

> ppa:damien-moore/ubuntu/codeblocks-stable

https://askubuntu.com/a/764048/547409

Which I then try the line of:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:damien-moore/ubuntu/codeblocks-stable
```

And at first it looks like it's about to succeed:

```
Current stable version of Code::Blocks IDE (16.01)
More info: https://launchpad.net/~damien-moore/+archive/ubuntu/codeblocks-stable
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it
```

But then it doesn't:

```
Error reading https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~damien-moore/+archive/ubuntu: Not Found
```

Can someone somewhere show me the solution to this terrible user interface nightmare of how I get Lubuntu 14.04 to install the latest codeblocks?

Comment: Shouldn't you drop `ubuntu/`  in `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:damien-moore/ubuntu/codeblocks-stable` and use `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:damien-moore/codeblocks-stable`  instead?

Comment: Thanks, your comment solved it. Should have been an answer.

Comment: Yeah, good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should drop `ubuntu/` in `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:damien-moore/ubuntu/codeblocks-stable` and use `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:damien-moore/codeblocks-stable` instead.